# Images keep disappearing while using language class in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Hi recently started coding and I have this controller which currently translates to the different languages.

Problem is with the images. When a language is selected, page switches to the desired language and translates it but no images are being displayed.

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');
}

public function index() {
    $this->lang->load('en_homepage_english_lang', 'English');

    $sess_data = array();
    $sess_data['default'] = 'english';
    $sess_data['slider_text_1']     = $this->lang->line('slider_text_1');
    $sess_data['slider_text_2']     = $this->lang->line('slider_text_2');

    $this->session->set_userdata('session_data', $sess_data);
    $data = $this->session->all_userdata();

    $data['title'] = "Vacation Rentals | Holiday Homes";
    $this->load->view('view', $data);
    }

public function select_language() {
    $language = $this->input->post('language');
    if ($language == 'english') {
    $data['selected'] = 'english';
    } else if ($language == 'english') {
    $data['selected'] = 'french';
    } else {
    $data['selected'] = 'Russian';

$this->lang->load('en_homepage_' . $language, $language);
$sess_data['select_lang'] = $this->lang->line('select_lang');
    $sess_data['default']           = $language;
    $sess_data['slider_text_1']     = $this->lang->line('slider_text_1');
    $sess_data['slider_text_2']     = $this->lang->line('slider_text_2');
    $sess_data['search_1']          = $this->lang->line('search_1');

$this->session->set_userdata('session_data', $sess_data);
$data = $this->session->all_userdata();

$this->load->view('view',$data);
}
```

I am wondering what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: I noticed you do not have end `}` at bottom of this  `$data['selected'] = 'Russian';`

Comment: Thanks @wolfgang1983.. May be Imissed to mention that..I thought may be because url was ending with `/select_language` hence I tried to redirect after language being choosen to homepage.. that fixed it..